# how to display data into linear highChart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying ti display data into a linear chart using `highChart`
i've tried many times. these are what i've tried to do but the chart still blank !

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options={
         chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
        title : {
          text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'   
       },
       subtitle : {
          text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
       },
        xAxis : {
          categories: ['11','jj','jj','11']
       },
        yAxis :{
          title: {
             text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
          },
          plotLines: [{
             value: 0,
             width: 1,
             color: '#808080'
          }]
       },   

        tooltip : {
          valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
       },

        legend : {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          borderWidth: 0
       },

        series : [{}]

    }
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 contentType : 'application/json',
 dataType: 'JSON',
 url: 'json',
 data: "",
 success: function(data){
     var array=[] ;
    $.each(data, function(i) {


        array.push(data[i].id); 

        })
          alert(array);
      options.series[0]= array;


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
});

});
  </script>
```

here `alert(array);` returns correctly an array of values from json . 
but still not recognized by `series` ! 
any help please ?

Comment: Can you tell what is stored in array?

Comment: this is what `alert(array);` returns  `120,168,200`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`series[0]` expects the data to be in a particular format.

Instead of doing `options.series[0]= array;`

Do,

```
options.series[0]= {"data":array};
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndts5j3f/1/)